# Many-to-many sorting in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

My application has an Entity Framework model containing a many-to-many relationship like the following:

```
ProductGroup: 
    Scalar: Id, Name
    Navigation: ProductGroupProduct
Product: 
    Scalar: Id, Sku, Description, etc.
    Navigation: ProductGroupProduct
ProductGroupProduct: 
    Scalar: ProductGroupId, ProductId, Position
    Navigation: Product, ProductGroup
```

Note how the intermediate table has a scalar property called Position that specifies the order in which a product should be displayed within a product group.

How would you write a LINQ query that returns a list of products in a given product group sorted by the Position property? If I was writing good ol' SQL I'd write something like this:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Sku, p.Description
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductGroupProduct pgp ON p.Id = pgp.ProductId 
WHERE pgp.ProductGroupId = @MyProductGroupId 
ORDER BY pgp.Position
```

But I can't figure the LINQ out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, your SQL won't work, because there is no `ProductGroup.Position`

But I *think* you want:

```
var q = from pgp in Context.ProductGroupProducts
        where pgp.ProductGroup.Id == id
        orderby pgp.Position
        select pgp.Product;
```

Comment: Sweet, that's what I needed. I kept trying to come at it from the Product side. It hadn't occurred to me that I could start in the middle. Thanks.

Oh, and I'll fix the SQL. That's what I get for typing it in to the editor here without checking it first.

Comment: You can do it from product, too, but it's *much* harder: `from p in Context.Products let pgp = (from pgp in p.ProductGroups where pgp.ProductGroup.Id == id).FirstOrDefault() where pgp != null orderby pgp.Position select p;`